# Magento 2 SOAP API WSDL anonymous access

Tags: visual-studio, magento, soap, wsdl, service-reference

I need to create a service reference to the Magento 2 SOAP API in my Visual Studio project. So I've created an Integration in the Magento backend, gave it All access and activated it.

But when I try to access the WSDL for (ie. the customer API) at  http://my.magento/soap/default?wsdl&services=customerCustomerRepositoryV1, I get the exception:

> Consumer is not authorized to access %resources

Ok, I get it. I need my access token to access these specific 'admin' API's. Because public API's like 'quoteGuestCartRepositoryV1' do work. When I get the full API list at http://my.magento/soap/default?wsdl_list=1 it also only lists public/guest API's.

No problem so far, but when I try to add the 'customerCustomerRepositoryV1' as a service reference in Visual Studio, of course the authorized exception is thrown. But I have no way of actually adding the access token to the header there.

Is there a way to get access to all WSDL's anonymously? Magento 1.x used to allow this.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I have exactly the same issue. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is a Magento error. The WSDL is not available anonymous anymore since a recent Magento release. I think it's a stupid decision by the devs.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5330#issuecomment-255222166

And for the 'solution': https://community.magento.com/t5/Programming-Questions/Magento-2-C-APIs-SOAP-problem/m-p/49677#M1206